# How to change the view of a viewpager fragment from its parent activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

[image]

In this image I have a list.

What I want is to change the view of this `Fragment` to the image given below.

[image: Image 2]

On the header, I want to add a search button. By clicking on the button the second image layout will appear and and by clicking the button again, it will fire a web service that returns with the response.

Comment: can you please elaborate the question ? what functionality you want ?

Comment: here is best example http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the search button.Initialize it in your main activity.In your project I suggest you to do with a single onclicklistner and a longclicklistner.For double tap you have to initialize a gesture.
I can provide you a code for any approaches but I strongly suggest you go with the first one.Reply mi accordingly I will provide you a code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are actually asking is "How to get a reference of the ViewPager's Fragment and do something with that".
If this is the case, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager), you see, its a very common and not that easy problem.
One way to solve ot correctly (providing that you are already using a FragmentStateAdapter) is doing something like the following:

In your activity:

```
  private CustomFragment mHomeFragment;
  private CustomFragment mOfferFragment;
  private CustomFragment mFavoriteFragment;
  private CustomFragment mInfoFragment;
```

and then, in your adapter

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return CustomFragment.newInstance(position, null);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        // save the appropriate reference depending on position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mHomeFragment = (CustomFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 1:
                mOfferFragment = (CustomFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 2:
                mFavoriteFragment = (CustomFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
            case 3:
                mInfoFragment = (CustomFragment) createdFragment;
                break;
        }
        return createdFragment;
    }
```

Doing that, it will allow you to do:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
mOfferFragment.doSomething();
```

in your parrent Activity